# Не запускается jar файл скомпилированный из JavaFX приложения

Tags: java, javafx

Не запускается jar файл скомпилированный из JavaFX приложения. При запуске через командную строку выдает ошибку

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run
> this application

Из Intellij запускается без ошибок.

в VM options добавил параметры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переменную PATH_TO_FX настроил так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так соответствующие параметры настроены и используются при запуске из командной строки?

Comment: А что ещё нужно настроить? Я хочу запускать просто jar файл

Comment: Вы настроили все параметры для запуска из IDE Idea.  Посмотрите в консоли идеи, какие параметры она использует при старте приложения, и сравните с теми, что используете вы.  Покажите текст команды, которую вы пишете в консоли для запуска приложения: `java ... ... -jar your.jar`

Comment: Добавил в вопрос скрин из командной строки

Comment: @Kolhoznik, выше пытаются объяснить то, что нужно при запуске из cmd нужно прописывать все те же параметры, которые ты прописал в IntellijIdea.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы приложение запускалось без них? Например на Java 8 если писать, то проблем нет. А на Java 11 что-то вот не пойму.

Comment: JavaFX была исключена из JDK 11: [Release Notes: JavaFX is no longer included in the JDK. It is now available as a separate download](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html).  Соответственно, придётся укзывать все необходимые параметры для виртуальной машины.

Comment: Да, я знаю что она была исключена. Но я не могу понять как указать эти необходимые параметры. Есть какой-то пример? Все примеры, которые я смотрел где описывается создание jar описывают примерно одно и тоже, добавить vm options, добавить в project structure атрефект и сделать build что я и делаю.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Создал bat файл со следующим содержимым и jar файл запустился

```
start javaw -jar --module-path "C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib" --add-modules javafx.fxml,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics MyApp.jar
```